# Problems with Classes and object.__new__ () not taking parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Factor:
    def __int__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

a = input("What is A?")
a = int(a)
b = input("What is B?")
b = int(b)
c = input("What is C?")
c = int(c)

e = Factor(a,b,c)
```

This is the error it returns for any class I create

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Alex Factoring Extra Credit.py", line 37, in <module>
    e = Factor(a,b,c)
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

It happens for any class I make and I have looked everywhere, uninstalled, and re-installed and yet I can not find a solution. I have copy and pasted classes I have found elsewhere and those will work, yet mine will work even though it is exactly the same. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't name your `__init__` properly, you forgot an `i`.

```
class Factor:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
```

Without an `__init__()` method, the arguments are sent to the parent `object.__new__()` method, which doesn't take any arguments.

Demo on Python 3.3 (slightly updated error message):

```
>>> class Factor:
...     def __int__(self, a, b, c):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...         self.c = c
... 
>>> Factor(1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
>>> class Factor:
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...         self.c = c
... 
>>> Factor(1, 2, 3)
<__main__.Factor object at 0x10a955050>
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. I feel like a fool now, but its always the little mistakes I guess.